Windows 11 Issue
I have just upgraded from W10 to W11 and have installed exactly the same versions of Anaconda and Neuron as I had on W10. However, when I run some code I have been running without problems for weeks in W10, I get an error message:
 File ~\OneDrive\My Documents\..... Mycode.py in <module>
    import neuron                     # NEURON package

  File c:\nrn\lib\python\neuron\__init__.py:139 in <module>
    import nrn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nrn'

I am using Navigator 2.1.4, Spyder 5.1.5 (Python 3.9.12) and Neuron 7.8.1
I have checked the paths and they seem OK. Any ideas?
I have tried re-installing, made sure it was the same version(s) as worked under W10 and checked paths.
